# tomcat 6 horizontal clustering?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6, cluster-computing, load-balancing

Please don't hesitate to ask for additional resource from me and don't hesitate to edit the question.

My `Load Balancing` configuration will be,

```
workers.java_home=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_25


#worker.list=worker1,worker2

worker.list=balancer

worker.worker1.port=8009
worker.worker1.host=localhost
worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.lbfactor=1

worker.worker2.port=8009
worker.worker2.host=192.168.100.84
worker.worker2.type=ajp13
worker.worker2.lbfactor=1

worker.balancer.type=lb
worker.balancer.balance_workers=worker1,worker2
worker.balancer.method=B
# Specifies whether requests with SESSION ID's 
# should be routed back to the same #Tomcat worker.

worker.balancer.sticky_session =True
```

In my httpd.conf,

```
<IfModule jk_module>

JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties
JkLogFile logs/mod_jk.log
JkLogLevel info

JkMount /MyApplication balancer
JkMount /MyApplication/* balance

</IfModule>
```

I have tried to configure the `Tomcat 6 Horizontal clustering`(different machine tomcat instances) with the help of this resource http://www.easywayserver.com/implementation-tomcat-clustering.htm.

The `load balancing` works for me.

But the `Horizontal Clustering` not works for me.

Hope our stack members help me.

Good answers are definitely appreciated.

Comment: belongs to http://serverfault.com

Comment: If the LB is ok but the Tomcat nodes do not see each other, it is probably something in server.xml <cluster> tag

Comment: What you mean by `The load balancing works for me.

But the Horizontal Clustering not works for me.` ?
May i assume Like load balancing works for `Vertical tomcat clustering( on single machine)`,But It's not work for `Horizontal Clustering`?